# No Administrator Account Found: Recovery Mode

Tags: security, recovery, monterey

So here’s the deal. I recently cloned my internal drive to a 1TB external SSD using SuperDuper!. It worked great, allowing me to boot into it, do everything I need to.

However, today, I went to Startup Security Utility in attempts to change the policy to Reduced Security to allow kernel extensions. However, it get “Recovery is trying to change system settings. No administrator account was found.”

I’ve looked around a bit, and found some post on this forum, but none directly relate— most are about not being able to boot into an external drive. I can do that. I also found some stuff about Secure Tokens, and how a secure token is needed.

Here’s what I’ve attempted:

- Delete .AppleSetupDone and re-run installation, creating a new Admin account
- Check both my original account (“landon”) and new admin account (“admin”) for secure tokens using `sysadminctl -secureTokenStatus landon` which shows enabled, and it showed disabled for admin.
- Generated a secure token for admin using `sysadminctl -adminUser landon -adminPassword <pass> -secureTokenOn admin -password <pass>`
- Run `diskutil apfs updatePreboot /`

Even after this, I am still seeing the “No administrator was found” error. I am using an M1 Mac Mini with Apple’s T2 chip.

How can I resolve the error outlined given the context of my situation?

Comment: I’m also on a M1 Mac Mini. So I have Apple’s T2 chip and whatnot.

Comment: I also facing this issue on Monterey 12.0.1 M1 chip.

Comment: Hi @gmexo you might need to edit a proper question here. Any ideas is a yes/no question and literally the best someone can do is ask you what you want to solve.

Answer (score 0):

No ideas since you didn’t ask a question past a “yes/no any ideas?” summary prompt.

- If you want to erase and reinstall that’s easy.
- If you want to use migration assistant to bring back the cloned files to a new macOS system, that’s easy.
- If you want instructions how to set up time machine, that’s easy.
- If you want to attempt copying files in target disk mode, that’s easy.
- If you want help looking at the cloned drive you made, that might be a bit more tricky, but easier than guessing what you’re trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I thought basic intuition would be considered. The title of this thread is “ No Administrator Account Found: Recovery Mode” and my question at the end of “Any ideas?” should be able to be inferred to: “How can I resolve the error outlined given the context of my situation?” If I wanted help on any of the ideas you mentioned, my title would accurately reflect: “How to erase macOS and reinstall?”.